# what is the reason of this output

Tags: python

The output of this program is
no
but I think it should be yes
because if condition is true when loop iterate last time(3rd time)

I know I am not right, please help me with the reason of "no"

```
def fun(a,k):
    for x in a:
        if x==k:
            return 'yes'
        else:
            return 'no'
print(fun([6,8,5],5))
```

Comment: `return` EXITs the function -so you check 6==5 and exit it with NO

Comment: Think about the first iteration, x will be set as value of 6 and k is value 5. So if x == k will be false thus you will immediatly go in the else part, this returns no and the function ends immediatly, you dont loop 3 times, you stop on the very first loop

Comment: Sometimes, you are so into loops, that the basics of programming flew away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the first iteration, x will be set as value of 6 and k is value 5. So if x == k will be false thus you will immediatly go in the else part, this returns no and the function ends immediatly, you dont loop 3 times, you stop on the very first loop.

this loop can never iterate more than once as you will either match or not but in either case you call return meaning that the function stops and exits returning that value. Do you mean to only return no if no value matched. I.E loop over and if you find a match return yes, If you have looped all the data but didnt match then say no

```py
def fun(a, k):
  for x in a:
    if x == k:
      return 'yes'
  return 'no'
print(fun([6, 8, 5], 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

The state of the function when it first enters is:

```
a = [6, 8, 5]
k = 5
```

So when we enter the for loop, `x = 6`.
Then you are checking:

```
if 6 == 5:
```

Hence, `else` returns "no".
Remember, a `return` statement immediately exits the function so none of the other elements are checked.

Perhaps what you are trying to do is:

```
def fun(a, k):
    for x in a:
        if x == k:
            return 'yes'
    return 'no'

print(fun([6,8,5],5))
```

Which will return 'no' once all the elements in `a` has been checked and none have been found to equal `k`